# Get data from username based url in YII framework

Tags: yii

I am using Yii framework to develop my website. I didn't activate any URL manager in my main.php file and every thing is working fine with the default url structure. But now i want get the data of user from the below url manner
**www.projectname.com/username**.

But as per the current url structure, i am unable to get the data and it is showing requested url not found on this server.

When I type **www.projectname.com/index.php/username** then it is working but users will not enter index.php and it is not good manner as i know.

So can anyone please guide me to get the data when the user enter the url like

**www.projectname.com/username**

Answer (score 0):

If your Username Controller Then
Use This In your config main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
    '<username>'    => 'user/profile',
```

Comment: Here username is not controller. It is the unique name assigned to user when any user registered into website.

Comment: Ok i chenged Answer try this

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I added above given code in config->main.php and tried with the below url.                                                                    localhost/projectname/abcd (here abcd is username assigned to user.). I got the below result when i tried. 

Not Found

The requested URL /projectname/abcd was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: I have done in several ways but i am unable to get the data from the below format www.projectname.com/username. I have changed the url manager from config/main.php and to hiden index.php from url i have added rewrite rules also in .htaccess file of root folder. But i am not getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `index.php` from the url. You can follow [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/) to learn how to do it.

Comment: i have changed .htaccess file from root folder and changed the paths of url managers in config/main.php file, but i am not getting the exact results